# Update no mongoDB está apagando o restante do documento

Tags: mongodb, react, mongoose, meteor, graphql

Tenho uma Collection estruturada assim:

```
{
  "_id": i43h21n5lk2354,
  "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-08-19T16:56:31.555Z"),
    "services" : {
            "facebook" : {
             ....
             name: "Michael Jackson"
             ....
             ....
}
```

Quero dar o update no campo ***nome***, mas ele apaga todos o restante do documento, estou ussando assim:

```
usersCollection.update(
 { _id: userId },
 {
  $set: {
    services: {
      facebook: {
        name: "Jackson Michael"
      }
    },
  }
})
```

Depois da atualização, e unica coisa que fica é o campo nome, todos os demais some.

```
 {
  "_id": i43h21n5lk2354,
  "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-08-19T16:56:31.555Z"),
    "services" : {
            "facebook" : {
             name: "Jackson Michael"       
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que ocorre é que você está pedindo para o Mongo substituir todo o conteúdo do sub-documento `services` por:

```
facebook: {
    name: "Jackson Michael"
}
```

Para que isso não ocorra você deve especificar o campo no seu set desta forma:

```
usersCollection.update(
{ _id: userId },
{
    $set: {
        "services.facebook.name" : "Jackson Michael"
    }
})
```

Comment: Exatamente, obrigado